# Incorrect .xliff file format after export stringsdict from Xcode (v.9.3)

Tags: xcode, xliff

After exporting .stringsdict file from Xcode into .xliff, part of data is lost. The problem appears in Xcode 9.3, in v.9.2 everything worked correctly, see the screenshot below.

Is there any idea how can this be fixed, why these data becomes lost/ damaged?

[image: screenshot of .xliff export in xCode 9.2 and 9.3]